# How to round 0.1333333333333333333333333333 to 0.133334 using C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

How can i round 0.1333333333333333333333333333 to 0.133334 using C#.
it's not necessary i get this value, could other values as well e.g;
0.1333333333333333333333333333 to 0.133334
0.1222222222222222222222222222 to 0.122223
0.1666666666666666666666666666 to 0.166667

Actually this is the hours in decimal, i am saving in database. if i don't save the correct value there would be difference in time.

Comment: If you're worried about precision like that, then store e.g. integer seconds (or milliseconds if you really need to!) in the database, not a decimal number you need to round.

Comment: `float` and `double` cannot store these numbers accurately, use `decimal` instead. Also, .NET `DateTime` is basically a wrapper struct around a 64-bit integer, which is enough to store timestamps up to year 9999 with 100ns precision.

Comment: use  long/int and store milliseconds or use decimal. float/double are woefully inadequate for what you want to do.

Comment: Basically (ceil(value*(10^precision)))/(10^precision), but note that the typical floating type variable can't necessarily store your result, as usual types store in binary digits.

Comment: @AKX i cant use minutes or milliseconds. i have to save it in hours in decimal right now. otherwise there would be a big change in database. can't bear that.

Comment: @Coder Too bad. Some rounding (and thus loss of precision and "difference in time") will then be inevitable.

Comment: Groo's comment nails it. You need to understand about floating points numbers!

Comment: I guess Groo didn't understand my question @TaW. AKX got my question. Sorry if my question isn't clear

Comment: Well if you already use `decimal` you can simply use `Decimal.Round(yourNumber, yourPrecision)`, no? (If you want to always round up you would have to add a small fraction like `0.00005m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.Round to round numbers

```
Math.Round(0.1333333333333333333333333333, 6);
```

If you convert to string, you can also specify the number of decimals to display.

```
0.1333333333333333333333333333.ToString("f6");
```

Your database may have a fixed format, but in .NET, you'll want to store it as DateTime (local time) or DateTimeOffset (universal time). You'll probably be able to manage by formatting/parsing to/from .NET and database formats with your rounding.

Just don't code against floating-point date types in .NET!